# Why Dockerized Node.js WebApp in a Windows Container fails to start

Tags: node.js, docker

I practice dockerizing a working web api in a windows container but the built image fails to start. I install `node:12.8.1` on base image `windows/servercore:ltsc2019`, then copy my WebApp content to a new folder in the image. Finally I run the Web App in the new image by `CMD ["npm", "start"]`. I build the image successfully. However I get errors when I run the container and I don't know how to troubleshoot. Could you please give me some direction for troubleshooting?

My Dockerfile

```html
# Dockerfile
# specify the builder ("builder" can be any tag)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 as builder

# install NODE and delete the installation file at completion
ENV NODE_VERSION 12.8.1
RUN powershell -Command \
  wget -Uri https://nodejs.org/dist/v%NODE_VERSION%/node-v%NODE_VERSION%-x64.msi -OutFile node.msi -UseBasicParsing ; \
  Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /q, /i, node.msi -Wait ; \
  Remove-Item -Path node.msi

# create and set the working directory
RUN mkdir "C:/app"
WORKDIR "C:/app"

# copy package.json to the working directory
COPY "package.json" .

# copy the rest to the working directory
COPY . .

# install all required packages
RUN npm install

# publish port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker build log

```html
Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 as builder
 ---> 486def14a6bd
Step 2/10 : ENV NODE_VERSION 12.8.1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3e31637477fe
Step 3/10 : RUN powershell -Command   wget -Uri https://nodejs.org/dist/v%NODE_VERSION%/node-v%NODE_VERSION%-x64.msi -OutFile node.msi -UseBasicParsing ;   Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /q, /i, node.msi -Wait ;   Remove-Item -Path node.msi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 42340811ffac
Step 4/10 : RUN mkdir "C:/app"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8aa6e02cb00
Step 5/10 : WORKDIR "C:/app"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0032d94ab432
Step 6/10 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 70969032ad95
Step 7/10 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8997a2a04ea
Step 8/10 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 7506fc55fa2d

> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> ejs@3.1.3 postinstall C:\app\node_modules\ejs
> node --harmony ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)

npm WARN pcms@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 617 packages from 794 contributors and audited 627 packages in 29.211s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing intermediate container 7506fc55fa2d
 ---> 634c8662bed5
Step 9/10 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in fa6eff469040
Removing intermediate container fa6eff469040
 ---> 287b80ad644a
Step 10/10 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Running in b178f342f286
Removing intermediate container b178f342f286
 ---> 0f2103478a01
Successfully built 0f2103478a01
Successfully tagged pcms:latest
```

And here is the log after I run "docker container run"

```html
docker run -dp 3000:3000 --name pcms pcms                                  
68db3442f8e51ee69b31ffb7a9437a413ec9877a91a70861cb594dfb6949f96b
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 68db3442f8e51ee69b31ffb7a9437a413ec9877a91a70861cb594dfb6949f96b encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF650AA9D2B: (caller: 00007FF650A5E13A) Exception(2) tid(39c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"npm start","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\app","Environment":{"NODE_VERSION":"12.8.1"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the docker run error is `The system cannot find the file specified`, there is something wrong with my command `npm start`. I removed the command `npm start`, build the image and run the container in interactive mode. To my horror, the `package.json`, `node_modules` and WebApp files are located at `C:\` not `C:\app` as I expect.The folder `C:\app` is empty. It proves that `WORKDIR "C:/app"` does not work. Further experiments show `WORKDIR C:/app` not working but `WORKDIR "C:\app"` works. I also find out that `CMD ["command", "args"]` and `ENTRYPOINT ["command", "args"]` do not work.

In summary, the changes I have made to make this work are

- Change `WORKDIR "C:/app"` to `WORKDIR "C:\app"`
- Change `CMD ["npm", "start"]` to `ENTRYPOINT npm start`